# What is sfc in sf Package of R?

Tags: r, sf

The following picture describes a simple feature collection of the package sf in R.
However, I don't get the meaning of sfc.
A feature collections consists of a set of simple features, three in the picture.

Each simple feature has a geometry, sfg, granted, but what is the role of sfc?

Why does is span multiple features?

In my understanding, a simple feature should consists of exactly one sfc, and each sfc of a set of geometries (sfg).

Can someone help me to understand the relationship between a simple feature (one row) and the geometry list-column (sfc)?

[image]

Answer (score 12):

I have found it the easiest to think of sfc as sf without any data - just the plain geometry.

The hierarchy the three object types in the sf universe:

- sfg is the lowest unit; it has only coordinates (according to the [well-known text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry) standard)
- sfc is a set of sfg's, plus - crucially! - information about interpretation of the coordinate reference system / are the coordinates in meters, or degrees? plane or sphere? if sphere, which one? this is highly standardized stuff, often described in terms of EPSG codes
- sf is a sfc geometry with data columns, in addition to the geometry

And because example is more than 1000 words, consider this code:

```
library(sf)

shape <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) # included with sf package

class(shape)
shape # data + geometry

geometry <- st_geometry(shape) # pull sfc from sf

class(geometry)
geometry # no data, but geometry is present

ashe <- geometry[[1]] # pull sfg from sfc

class(ashe)
ashe # a polygon, but without CRS - no way to interpret the coordinates without external information
```

You will see information disappearing as you go from complex to simple objects.

Comment: So, just to be clear, all features/rows of an sf-object (green box) share the same sfc-object (red box)? In orther words, n features, 1 sfc consisting of n geometries?

Comment: A sfc _consists_ of a set of sfg's + infomation on how to interpret the numbers in the coordinates (coordinate reference system). So yes, n individual geometries in a sfc with n rows + 1 CRS definition